# typescript method with type as parameter

Tags: class, typescript

Given this class hierarhcy

```
export class A {
  static m() { return 'a'};
}


export class B extends A {
  static m() { return 'b'};
}


export class C extends A {
  static m() { return 'c'};
}
```

I need a method taking an array of classes (not instance) extending `A` and calls `m()` on each element of the array:

```
function looper(classes: A[]) {
  classes.forEach(c => c.m());
}
```

This expects an array of instances of A or its subclasses.

**How can I have a method that takes as argument classes that extend A?**

Generics as pointed out by @Oscar Paz

**EDIT 1**

Moreover the input to looper needs to be stored in a property of an object:

```
export class Container {
  public klazzes: A[];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like "classes: typeof(A)[]" should be the parameter for looper?

Comment: In typescript 2.5.3 "classes: typeof(A)[]" does not compile

Comment: It was a question asked to get a clarification!!

Comment: My comment didn't mean any offense, I actually thought it was a code suggestion :)

Comment: You are in a hurry! :) Is that what you seek to send a type of class A[] as parameter?

Comment: Yes indeed that's it

Comment: public klazzes: A[];
is not the same as   
public klazzes: T[];
Please check out my answer for the explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, using generics:

```
function callM<T extends typeof A>(arr: T[]): void {
    arr.forEach(t => t.m());
}
```

Now you can do:

```
callM([A, B, C]); // OK
callM([A, B, string]); // Error
```

If you want to store the values:

```
class Container {
    public klazzes: (typeof A)[];
}
const cont: Container = new Container();
callM(cont.klazzes);
```

Comment: thank you! That works indeed! I updated my question with a related problem of where the input to the method needs to be stored. I'm having a hard time trying to apply the generics concept in that case

Comment: I missed the edited part while typing my answer .. too late again

Comment: Thank you very much @Oscar Paz, I owe you big time

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something you were looking for - on top of what @Oscar suggested you can create a generic class to store the array in a property of type `T[]` like below .

```
export class A {
  static m() { return 'a'};
}


export class B extends A {
  static m() { return 'b'};
}


 export class C extends A {
  static m() { return 'c'};
}

 export class Container<T extends typeof A> {
    public klazzes: T[];
    constructor() {
        this.klazzes = [];
    }

   public callM<T extends typeof A>(arr: T[]): void {
       arr.forEach(t => 
           console.log(t.m())
        );
   }
}

// usage 
let cont = new Container();
cont.klazzes = [A, B, C];
cont.callM(cont.klazzes);
```

Here is a working link

[Working demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0A%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20m()%20%7B%20return%20'a'%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20m()%20%7B%20return%20'b'%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20class%20C%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20m()%20%7B%20return%20'c'%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20class%20Container%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20A%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20klazzes%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.klazzes%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20callM%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20A%3E(arr%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr.forEach(t%20%3D%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(t.m())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20cont%20%3D%20new%20Container()%3B%0D%0Acont.klazzes%20%3D%20%5BA%2C%20B%2C%20C%5D%3B%0D%0Acont.callM(cont.klazzes)%3B)

Comment: Not what I needed, but will come handy in the future maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Container<T extends typeof A> {
    public klazzes: T[];
}
```

[image]

is not the same as

```
export class Container<T extends typeof A> {
    public klazzes: A[];
}
```

Typing the array as a specific type 'A' undermines the purpose of generics. so, I guess you would want to use the template type 'T'

[image]